# Badrequest error when adding multiple routes to Azure FrontDoor Profile (Standard)

Tags: azure-front-door

We've got an Azure Frontdoor Profile (Standard), for which i'm trying to add multiple routes to a single endpoint (using two origin groups, each with one origin). I think this should be possible after having read the MS docs ([afd route docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-configure-route)).  Reason for this is that we are going to host multiple SPA applications that use APIs.  So each frontend app will need a backend app that will be access via a backend url.

I'm trying to add the two routes using az-cli (they are linked to two apps in two different regions via custom domains).  The first one works.  However, i get an error when adding the second one:

```
(BadRequest) The route domains, paths and protocols configuration has a conflict. More information: Domain: endpoint01, Path pattern: /Applications, Protocol: Http cannot be added to Route frontend01 as this combination already exists in Endpoint endpoint01, Route backend01..
Code: BadRequest
```

Command #1

```
az afd route create -g resource-group-01 --profile-name profile-01 --endpoint-name endpoint01 --route-name backend01 --patterns-to-match /* --origin-group origingroup1 --supported-protocols Http Https --custom-domains backend-custom-domain --forwarding-protocol MatchRequest --https-redirect Enabled --link-to-default-domain Enabled
```

Command #2

```
az afd route create -g resource-group-01 --profile-name profile-01 --endpoint-name endpoint01 --route-name frontend01 --patterns-to-match /* --origin-group origingroup1--supported-protocols Http Https --custom-domains frontend-custom-domain --forwarding-protocol MatchRequest --https-redirect Enabled --link-to-default-domain Enabled
```

I may not understand the structure of the route objects in AFD.  Essentially what i am trying to do is:

- have one AFD (that will host multiple applications)
- with one endpoint
- with two origin groups per application (with one origin each)
- - one frontend origin group with custom domain
- - one backend origin group custom domain

Once we have this working, we will then start loadbalancing our applications as well (

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue with "routing rule configuration", because wildcard pattern which is exist in Routing Rule1.

In 2nd Routing Rule also having wildcard pattern, so routing rule won't allow because tits already exist with Rule1

[image]

Solution:
Please another route along with wildcard via comma Seperator.
Example:
/* *, /api/* *

```
az afd route create -g resource-group-01 --profile-name profile-01 --endpoint-name endpoint01 --route-name frontend01 --patterns-to-match /*,/api/* --origin-group origingroup1--supported-protocols Http Https --custom-domains frontend-custom-domain --forwarding-protocol MatchRequest --https-redirect Enabled --link-to-default-domain Enabled
```

In Portal, route rule will be visible like this.

[image]

[image]

NOTE: If no exact match Paths, look for routing rules with a wildcard path that matches.